# How to remove uninstalled app from All apps list in Windows 10

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup, uninstallation

I uninstalled a program from my Windows 10 but the program folder still appears in my "All apps" list from the Start menu. Before going any further, however, I should mention that the installation and uninstall were performed by Inno Setup Studio 5 for a program that I wrote. After using debug mode to install/uninstall a few times, the Inno Setup install has "dirtied" my Windows 10 "All apps" list.

If I try clicking on the program in "All apps", nothing happens--which makes sense given that the program no longer exists. I confirmed that the uninstall did actually remove the actual files and folder from C:\Program Files (x86).

I looked in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs and in %appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs but cannot see the folder/files there.

I thought that maybe the "All apps" list also read values from the registry so I searched the registry in regedit but could not find it there.

In summary, I don't know why All apps still shows the program. Any tips would be very helpful to clean up this annoyance, thank you!

Forgot to mention that the program is not in "Programs & Features" nor in "Apps & features" after uninstall

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
```

These are shortcuts that were not removed when the app was uninstalled.  Delete them from this location to remove from All Apps list.